# How do I limit the amount of requests to an API using React?

Tags: reactjs, api

I am a student and we just started looking at APIs, using the https://openweathermap.org API I tried to get the forecast for Stockholm, Sweden. Didn't get very far because for some reason, I sent alot of requests, which blocked me from sending more. And don't really know what is causing it.

Would really appreciate feedback/ explanation to what I am doing wrong and can improve.
Thanks in advance!

This is all I have done so far, and placed `<InitialContainer>` inside function App()

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const InitialForecast = () =>{

    const[initial, setInital] = useState();

    let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Stockholm&appid=MyID";
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data =>{

        setInital(data);
        // console.log(data.name);
       
    })

    return(<>
        <h2>{initial.name}</h2>       
    </>)

}
export default InitialForecast;
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop. You're calling the API on every render, and after calling `setInitial` which re-renders, which re-fetches, etc. Most likely you need a `useEffect`.

Comment: @BrianThompson thanks alot! will try it when I am not blocked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When the component renders the first time, you fetch the data and use `setInitial(data)` which causes a re-render of the component. As the component gets re-rendered, you fetch the API again, and use `setInitial(data)` again, and so forth.

What you need to do to get the data just once when the component is first rendered is put the fetch statement inside a `useEffect` hook with no dependencies, like

```js
const [initial, setInital] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Stockholm&appid=MyID";

  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data =>{
        setInital(data);  
  })
}, [])

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with your code is that your component re-renders as soon as it updates the `data` variable. Try putting the request into the `useEffect()`-Hook.

The useEffect-Hook runs **after** the component is done rendering. Any state changes won't re-render the dom again -> no fetch-loop.

You can read more about how useEffect works in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

For Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V action you can use this snippet:

````js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const InitialForecast = () =>{

    const[initial, setInital] = useState();

    let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Stockholm&appid=MyID";
    
    useEffect(()=>
        fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data =>{
        setInital(data);
    }), [])

    return(<>
        <h2>{initial.name}</h2>       
    </>)

}
export default InitialForecast;
```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is completely wrong. You cant call APIs and setState hooks directly inside react component this will create infinite loops,
On your first API success it will set `setInital(data);` and this will render the component again and it will call your API again

Solution

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const InitialForecast = () =>{

    const[initial, setInital] = useState();
    const getIntialData = () => {
        let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Stockholm&appid=MyID";
        fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            setInital(data);
        })
    }
    useEffect(()=> {
         getIntialData()
     }, [])

    return(<>
        <h2>{initial.name}</h2>       
    </>)

}
export default InitialForecast;
```

The useEffect with empty array in second argument will only call at the first render of component similar to componentWillMount

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I should have added that I also just started learning React, so these things are completely new.

Comment: I have a follow up question if you don't mind. When I the change according to your solution, then return a <h1> with initial.name. It prints out, but if I refresh the page it disappears and I get error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`. Do you know the cause of this?

Comment: Add an empty object as an intial value for variable "initial" `useState({})`

Comment: Thank you once again! I am experiencing the same problem with `{initial.weather[0].description}`, do I need to initiate an object within the object or am I complete lost?

Comment: You need to check does initial. weather is undefined or not

Comment: I solved it by changing `useState({})` to `useState(null)`